# Monitor (semaphore) in java

Tags: java, multithreading, monitor

I have been reading and performing practical in java from the Book "The Complete Reference " by Herbert Schildt.
 In this book in Thread chapter, there is a section of Interthread Communication.
 One side book says no other synchronized method of an instance is executed by any thread until a current thread terminates but have a look at the program below.
 In output it executes both synchronized methods how could someone explain what is happening?

output:

> put :0
>   put :1
>   put :2
>   put :3
>   put :4
>   get :4
>   get :4
>   get :4
>   get :4
>   get :4
>   get :4
>   get :4
>   get :4
>   get :4
>   get :4
>   get :4
>   get :4
>   get :4
>   get :4
>   get :4
>   get :4
>   get :4
>   get :4
>   get :4
>   get :4
>   get :4
>   get :4
>   get :4

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Q q=new Q();

        Producer p=new Producer(q);
        Consumer c=new Consumer(q); 
    }
}

class Q {
    int n;

    synchronized int get(){
        System.out.println("get :"+n);
        return n;
    }
    synchronized void put(int n){
        this.n=n;
        System.out.println("put :"+n);
    }
}



class Producer implements Runnable{
    Q q;
    Producer(Q q){
        this.q=q;
        new Thread(this,"Producer").start();

    }
    public void run(){
        int i=0;
        while(true){
            q.put(i++);
        }
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable{
    Q q;
    Consumer(Q q){
        this.q=q;
        new Thread(this,"Consumer").start();
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            q.get();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add output too in question

Comment: just a sec and i also update the program.

Comment: output is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting from [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html),

> it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the
>   same object to interleave. When one thread is executing a synchronized
>   method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized
>   methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first
>   thread is done with the object

So there, termination means not the thread itself (*e.g: `Consumer` does not wait until `Producer` dies or completed, vice-versa)*, but execution completion of any synchronizing methods/blocks.

To answer your question, still `Producer` and `Consumer` both can run using `Q`, but both `get` and `put` methods will never be executed at same time, because of implicit synchronization with object instance with keyword `synchronized`.

Only one method will be executed by either `Producer` or `Consumer` at any given time, i.e. when `get` is called by `Consumer`, `Producer` cannot call `put` and vice-versa.

Comment: So that means consumer only wait until producer executes code in  void run() of it. But how. In my output. Get 4 is executed many times?

Comment: @DhruvPatel: your `Consumer.run()` just repeats `get()`s - there is *no* guarantee as to which threads will advance once `get()` returns, and at least up to the next `put()`, `4` is the value to be expected. (Then, there's [Thread.yield()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#yield()).)

Comment: @DhruvPatel  The number of get or put lines printed on the console are totally dependent on the underlying operating system scheduler, unless you use java concurrency constructs (locks, semaphore etc.) to control them. There is no guarantees that there will be always N number of get lines printed after M number of put lines.